# Using \pause inside a tikzpicture environment in a beamer presentation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pause

I am preparing a presentation using `beamer`. 
I would like to show a picture written using `tikz` in two steps.

This is my first attempt:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}      
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray, thick] (-3,2) -- (3,2);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (-3.5, 2) -- (-3,2);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (3, 2) -- (3.5,2);
\draw[gray, thick] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (-3.5, 0) -- (-3,0);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (3, 0) -- (3.5,0);
\draw[gray, thick] (-2,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[gray, thick] (-1,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[gray, thick] (0,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[gray, thick] (-2.5,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[gray, thick] (-1.5,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[gray, thick] (-0.5,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[red, very thick] (0.5,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[gray, thick] (1,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[gray, thick] (1.5,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[gray, thick] (2,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[gray, thick] (2.5,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);

\draw (3.5, 1) node [anchor = west]{$M$};

\pause

\draw (0.5, 0) node [anchor = north, red]{$N$};
\draw[red, very thick] (-3.3,1.7) -- (2.6,1.7);
\draw[red, very thick, dotted] (-3.8, 1.7) -- (-3.3,1.7);
\draw[red,  very thick, dotted] (2.6, 1.7) -- (3.1,1.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I.e. I've just used the command `\pause` inside the `tikzpicture` environment. Unfortunately this result is quite unsatisfactory because the blue strip on the bottom (produced by the theme `Berlin`) does not appear immediately, but at the second step.

How could I solve my problem?

Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using the `\pause` command, use the `\onslide` command.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}      
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usetheme{Berlin}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\onslide<1->{
\draw[gray, thick] (-3,2) -- (3,2);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (-3.5, 2) -- (-3,2);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (3, 2) -- (3.5,2);
\draw[gray, thick] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (-3.5, 0) -- (-3,0);
\draw[gray, thick, dotted] (3, 0) -- (3.5,0);
\draw[gray, thick] (-2,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[gray, thick] (-1,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[gray, thick] (0,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[gray, thick] (-2.5,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[gray, thick] (-1.5,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[gray, thick] (-0.5,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[red, very thick] (0.5,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[gray, thick] (1,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[gray, thick] (1.5,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[gray, thick] (2,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);
\draw[gray, thick] (2.5,1) ellipse (0.6 and 1);

\draw (3.5, 1) node [anchor = west]{$M$};
}
\onslide<2>{
\draw (0.5, 0) node [anchor = north, red]{$N$};
\draw[red, very thick] (-3.3,1.7) -- (2.6,1.7);
\draw[red, very thick, dotted] (-3.8, 1.7) -- (-3.3,1.7);
\draw[red,  very thick, dotted] (2.6, 1.7) -- (3.1,1.7);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]